# How can I generate several output formats from one RuboCop::RakeTask using "formatters"?

Tags: ruby, rake, rubocop

For integrating our Rubocop reports into Jenkins, I'd like to generate both Checkstyles -- XML output and HTML output -- in one go.

I can achieve this when running Rubocop directly:

```
$ rubocop -r rubocop/formatter/checkstyle_formatter \
    --format html --out reports/html/index.html \
    --format RuboCop::Formatter::CheckstyleFormatter --out reports/checkstyle-result.xml
```

However, I can't figure out how to achieve the same result with `RuboCop::RakeTask` and the `formatters` array.

Here's what I have tried:

**Using multiple --out entries in options**

```
RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:rubocop_ci) do |t|
   t.formatters = ['html', 'RuboCop::Formatter::CheckstyleFormatter']
   t.options = ['--out', 'reports/checkstyle-result.xml',
                '--out', 'reports/html/index.html']
end
```

This generates `reports/checkstyle-result.xml`, but prints the HTML output to `STDOUT` (presumably, Rubocop ignores the second `--out` parameter).

**Put everything into the options, and ignore formatters completely**

```
RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:rubocop_ci2) do |t|
    t.options = ['--format', 'RuboCop::Formatter::CheckstyleFormatter', 
                 '--out', 'reports/checkstyle-result.xml',
                 '--format', 'html',
                 '--out', 'reports/html/index.html']
end
```

This works, but is ugly; is it possible to use multiple entries in `formatters` with different output files?